# JNDI name already bound for ConnectionFactory even after deletion

Tags: java, weblogic, jndi, jdeveloper

I am working on Jdeveloper 11.1.1.6 on a web application which uses ConnectionFactory. I have been having problem with the JNDI naming in the application. I keep on getting NameAlreadyBoundException for the JNDI name that I am using. I had earlier deployed another application which used same JNDI name but it has been undeployed and deleted from the deployment directory. Changing the JNDI name is not an option. So I tried many other options

- I deleted the JMS server, JMS module, Queue, ConnectionFactory from the integerated weblogic console
- I undeployed the application from the server via the Jdeveloper interface
- I deleted the web application from the deployment directory in o.j2ee\drs folder
- I checked in the config\jms folder in the DefaultDomain server whether some residual file is present for the ConnectionFactory

The JNDI binding is done through the weblogic console only so the problem couldn't be due to the code of the application. I have been trying to solve this for more than 20 days now but am at a dead end now. Any ideas what could be the problem due to which I am getting the NameAlreadyBoundException for the ConnectionFactory?

I understand that reinstalling Jdeveloper will solve this problem but nuking the whole thing doesn't seem like a good solution.

Comment: Maybe this will help shed some light on it. Go into your admin console, click your Server link, and choose `View JNDI tree`. Find the JNDI name you are attempting to use and click on it. Then you can see details about the bound object (like where it's running). Maybe then you can find the cause

Comment: @better_use_mkstemp I tired that but the JNDI name was not present there.

Comment: @better_use_mkstemp I checked again and the JNDI name was present under tree jms -> qcf -> QueueConnectionFactory although the exact JNDI name was different. But how do I check what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you are on weblogic, try searching with the keyword ConnectionFactory in search-box. It will show up with all the occurrences of the JNDI. Make sure JNDI is unique. Remove or change the one which is not required. Hope this helps.